# Java won't recognize defined variables?

Tags: java

In `actionPerformed` it seems that all variables (submit, msg, input) "cannot be resolved" according to Eclipse. In my experience (of which I have very little) this means that I have not defined the variables. But, as you can see in the code, I have defined them. Submit is a JButton, msg is a string, input is a JTextField.

```
package levels;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.util.*;

public class LevelOne extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private Object msg;

    public void one(){

        setTitle("Conjugator");
        setSize(400,400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images/LevelOneBG.gif")));
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JTextArea area = new JTextArea("You enter a castle. A Goblin demands you correct his sentences!");
        add(area);
        setVisible(true);

        //these aren't being called to actionPerformed
        JButton submit = new JButton("Check sentence");
        submit.addActionListener(this);
        setVisible(true);
        JTextField input = new JTextField("Ich spielen Golf.");
        input.setActionCommand("input");
        add(input);
        input.addActionListener(this);
        setVisible(true);

        String msg = ("Test successful");
    }   

    //this should be successfully locating and utilizing "submit", "input" and "msg", but it won't
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == submit) {
            msg = submit.getText();

            //!!  Display msg only **after** the user has pressed enter.
            input.setText(msg); 
        }

    }
}
```

I am aware some of my imports are unnecessary.

P.S., i'm making a small text adventure game for my German class

Comment: Indent your code sanely, please, it's hard to tell what the scope of things is supposed to be.

Comment: Sorry. I'll keep that in mind in the future. In the mean time, do you have a solution to my problem?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html.  You should read this tutorial with attention to the differences between instance variables (fields) and local variables (variables defined in methods).  Particularly the part that reads: "*local variables are only visible to the methods in which they are declared; they are not accessible from the rest of the class.*"

Comment: @user2426434 I don't because I can't tell if the variables are variables or fields because your indentation is wonky and makes it too hard to see where methods start or end. (Okay, so I'm not really putting any effort into following your code. Point is, formatting is a very strong visual hint into the structure of code.)

Answer (score 3):

You defined the variables as *local* variables in the method `one()`. By definition, local variables are... local. They're visible only in the block here they're defined. To be visible in `one()` and in `actionPerformed()`, they should be defined as fields of the class.

An alternative would be to use an anonymous inner class defined in the `one()` method to defined your action listener, but given that you don't master variables yet, you'd better leave anonymous classes for a bit later. Swing is a complex framework, and you should probably do some more basic programming exercises before doing Swing.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `input` and `submit` variables are not accessible in the `actionPerformed` method.

Make the `input` and `submit` variables class members, like this:

```
pubilc class LevelOne {
    private JTextField input = new JTextField("Ich spielen Golf.");
    private Object msg;
    private JButton submit = new JButton("Check sentence");


    public void one() { ... }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have seen that.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of those variables is the one() method only. If you want them available to the whole class put them at the top next to msg.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `submit` is defined as a local variable in the method `one()`.

It is not available in the method `actionPerformed()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your variable outside the method 'One' like:

```
private JButton submit = new JButton("Check sentence");

public void one(){
    // whatever goes there
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   // submit is now working 
   if (e.getSource() == submit) {
   }
}
```